# How to track Stripe purchases coming from Adwords?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

Is there a way to track in Google Analytics the purchases made through Stripe and coming from an Adwords ad?

And if it *is* possible, can I also track purchases that took place 30 days or more after the user clicked on my ad?